# Define namespaceResolver in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, xpath

I can't figure out how to define properly the `namespaceResolver` function in `TypeScript`. I have the following `resolver` function:

```
(prefix: string): string => {
    if (prefix === "wms") {
        return "http://www.opengis.net/wms";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

But the compiler complains that:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(prefix: string) => string' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'XPathNSResolver'.   Property
>   'lookupNamespaceURI' is missing in type '(prefix: string) => string'.

If I check the implementation in `lib.dom.d.ts`, the `lookupNaemspaceURI`'s return value is `string` too. So I have no idea how should I fix this.

*lib.dom.d.ts*:

```
interface XPathNSResolver {
    lookupNamespaceURI(prefix: string): string;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the whole code:

```
doc.evaluate("/wms:WMS_Capabilities/wms:Service/wms:Name", doc, (prefix: string): string => {
                    if (prefix === "wms") {
                        return "http://www.opengis.net/wms";
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out.

I created an `XPathNSReslover` first:

```
private xpathResolver: XPathNSResolver = {
        lookupNamespaceURI: prefix => {
            if (prefix === "wms") {
                return "http://www.opengis.net/wms";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
```

Then I just use this `xpathResolver` in my `evaluate` method implementation:

```
doc.evaluate("/wms:WMS_Capabilities/wms:Service/wms:Name", doc, this.xpathResolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this issue, I would recommend using 'xpath-ts' instead of 'xpath'. With xpath-ts, convoluted typing (such as in the other solution) can be avoided.